# isolate scope communication from directive to directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am new to AngularJS and got confused with directive concept.
I am updating scope.markers in my second directive via $scope.delete function but changes are not reflecting on first directives,as I am using two way data binding isolate scope, so it should reflect. any solution will be a great help.

I have my first directive as:

```
app.directive('damageDiagram', function () {
  return {
    retrict: 'AE',
    scope: {
      imgsrc: '=', markers: '=', pointsrc: '=', dtype:'='
    },
    templateUrl: 'app/components/inspections/damage-diagram.html',
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {            
    }
  }
});
```

and second directive as:

```
 app.directive('damageMarker', function ($mdDialog,inspectionService,$timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        require: '?^damageDiagram',
        scope: {
            marker: '=',
            pointsrc: '=',
            dtype:'=',
            markers: '='
        },
        template: '<img ng-src="{{pointsrc}}" />',
        link: function (scope, elem, attr) {
            elem.on("click",function(e){                
                showDialog();
                function showDialog($event) {
                   var parentEl = angular.element(document.body);
                   $mdDialog.show ({
                     parent: parentEl,
                     targetEvent: $event,
                     template:
                      '<form name="clientForm" novalidate >'+
                       '<md-dialog aria-label="List dialog">' +
                       '  <md-dialog-content>'+                           
                            '<md-input-container>'+
                              '<md-select ng-model="dtypeValue" class="dialog-close" placeholder="Select dtype">'+
                                '<md-option ng-repeat="opt in dtype">{{opt}}</md-option>'+
                              '</md-select>'+
                            '</md-input-container>'+
                            '<md-input-container class="md-block">'+
                                '<label>Comment</label>'+
                                '<input  required name="name" ng-model="comment" class="dialog-close">'+
                                '<div ng-messages="clientForm.name.$error">'+
                                    '<div ng-message="required">This is required.</div>'+                                    
                                '</div>'+
                            '</md-input-container>'+
                       '  </md-dialog-content>' +
                       '  <div class="md-actions" layout="row" layout-align="end center">' +
                       '    <md-button ng-click="closeDialog()" class="md-primary">' +
                       '      Close' +
                       '    </md-button>' +
                           '<md-button ng-disabled="clientForm.$invalid" ng-click = "save()" class="md-primary">'+
                                'Save'+
                            '</md-button>'+
                            '<md-button ng-disabled="clientForm.$invalid" ng-click = "delete()" class="md-primary">'+
                                'Delete'+
                            '</md-button>'+
                       '  </div>' +
                       '</md-dialog>'+
                       '</form>',                     
                     controller: DialogController
                  });
                  function DialogController($scope, $mdDialog) {
                    $scope.dtypeValue = scope.dtype[scope.marker.dtype.toUpperCase()];
                    $scope.dtype = scope.dtype;
                    $scope.comment = scope.marker.comment;
                    $scope.marker = scope.marker;
                    $scope.closeDialog = function() {
                      $mdDialog.hide();
                    }
                    $scope.save = function(){                        
                        console.log($scope.marker.id);
                        console.log($scope.dtypeValue);
                        console.log($scope.comment);
                        var dataSend = {};
                        dataSend.id = $scope.marker.id;
                        dataSend.comment = $scope.comment;
                        for(var key in $scope.dtype) {
                            if($scope.dtype[key] == $scope.dtypeValue) {
                                dataSend.dtype = key;
                            }
                        }
                        inspectionService.updateDiagram(dataSend).then(function(response){
                            console.debug("response ; "+response);
                            $mdDialog.hide();                            
                            scope.marker.id = response.id;
                            scope.marker.comment = response.comment;
                            scope.marker.dtype = response.dtype;
                        });
                    }
                    $scope.delete = function(){
                        var dataSend = {};
                        dataSend.id = $scope.marker.id;      
                        var param = {};
                        param.inspection=$scope.marker.inspection;                                          
                        inspectionService.deleteDiagramMarker(dataSend).then(function(response){                                                                                    
                            inspectionService.getDiagram(param).then(function(response){                            
                                $timeout(function() {
                                    scope.$apply(function(){
                                       scope.markers = response.results;
                                  })                                  
                                },2000);                                                                
                                console.debug("response ; "+response);
                                $mdDialog.hide();
                            });       
                        });
                    }

                  }
                }
            });
            console.log(scope.marker.top, scope.marker.left, elem);
        }
    }
});
```

My html code for damage-diagram directive is as follows:

```
<damage-diagram imgsrc="imgsrc" pointsrc="pointsrc" dtype="dtype"
  markers="inspection.damage_diagram">
</damage-diagram>
```

and my html code for damage-directive is as follow:

```
<div style="position:relative">
    <img id="23467129" ng-src="{{imgsrc}}" style="position:relative" width="100%" />
    <div ng-repeat="marker in markers"
         marker="marker"
         markers="markers"
         dtype="dtype"
         pointsrc="pointsrc"
         damage-marker>
    </div>    
</div>
```

controller is as follows:

```
app.controller('InspectionDetailCtrl', ['$scope', 'inspectionService', '$stateParams', 'Restangular','$rootScope',
    function ($scope, inspectionService, $stateParams, Restangular, $rootScope) {
        $scope.updateDamageImage = {};
        $scope.insp_id = $stateParams.inspId;
        $scope.damageImagesShow = false;
        $scope.comments = [];
        $scope.types = [];
        $scope.selectTypeDelete = false;
        $scope.commentDelete = false;
        $scope.selectTypeDeleteBefore = true;
          $scope.commentDeleteBefore = true;

        init($scope.insp_id);
        console.log("Fetching details for scope", $scope.insp_id);
        function init(insp_id)
        {
            inspectionService.inspections.customGET(insp_id, {type: 'full'})
            .then(function (data) {
                $scope.inspection = data;
            }, function (err) {
                $scope.inspection = null;
            });
        }        
        $scope.pointsrc="app/components/inspections/pointer.png";
        $scope.dtype = {
            'S': 'Scratch (minor)',
            'DS': 'Deep Scratch',
            'D': 'Dents',
            'WD': 'Wheel Damage',
            'CW': 'Cracked Window',
            'FT': 'Flat Tire',
            'BL': 'Broken (lights)'
        };
    }]);
```

Comment: good work....but it will be fulfilled if you share your relevant ctrl.js

Comment: ctrl.js has been shared

Answer (score 0):

First of all two way binding in directive doesn't works like that any change reflected in main controller can be seen in directive but not other way any change in directive won't be reflected in main controller.

But there is a solution you can create an object in main controller

```
var x={};
x.value='to be passed in directive'
```

then you use same variable in directive since only once instance of object is created so any change in any directive will be reflected everywhere.